# Can a subflow pick up execution context from parent sub-flow?

Tags: mule

I have a Main flow m1 which refers to a subflow s1 and s1 refers furthur to a subflow s2.

Now the issue is I know that s1 can pick up context from m1 but can s2 pick up the same from s1(the calling flow of s2)?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself and check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all sub-flows act like macros and will run in the context of the parent flow even if it's chained via another sub-flow.